# How to know workflow foundation resumebookmark succeed or failed?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have been trying to use Microsoft Workflow Foundation 4.0 in .Net Framework 4.5.

I've been following tutorials from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activities.workflowapplication.resumebookmark?view=netframework-4.8

I'm facing a problem with `ResumeBookmark` method.

I receive `BookmarkResumptionResult` success, but the resume actually failed. From my understanding, getting `BookmarkResumptionResult` success only meant that the bookmark resumption was successfully scheduled.

How to find out whether the actual resumption succeed or failed?

Comment: improved formatting

Comment: Can you show what error your getting after the resume? You can attach a handle for the Workflow Application's "OnUnhandledException" property and log the exception there to see.